React Planby Timeline: One text per row
I am using - https://planby.app/. This is a timeline, schedules creation library to quickly implement timelines.
I am specifically aiming to display one text per row within my timelines. By far, I have been able to show it for each block like below -
PlanBy Timeline
Tried multiple approaches but didn't work out.

Hi. Welcome to SO. "Tried multiple approaches": what approaches? You should add relevant code/details to your question. If it's code try to make sure it's a [mcve]. Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
